# Expressing the negation of $[\neg(p\land\neg q)]\land\neg r$ without $\neg,\land,\lor$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

> Negate $[\neg(p\land\neg q)]\land\neg r$ and replace the resulting formula by an equivalent which does not involve $\neg, \land$ or $\lor$.

Can someone tell me how to get through this question? Help!

I start with $$\neg[[\neg(p\land\neg q)]\land\neg r] = (p\land\neg q)\lor(r).$$ Is that right so far?

Comment: If your result can use _neither_ of $\neg$, $\land$, or $\lor$, then what _can_ you use?

Comment: Check my question again. And you should use the quantifiers (universal and existential) signs as well as the implication sigh instead of those mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By DeMorgan's

$$\lnot\Big(\lnot(p \land \lnot q) \land \lnot r\Big) \equiv (p \land \lnot q) \lor r$$

Now use the equivalency of $\lnot a \lor b \equiv a \rightarrow b\tag{1}$ and so $a \lor b \equiv \lnot a \rightarrow b\tag{2}$

---

$$\begin{align} (p \land \lnot q) \lor r & \equiv \lnot (p \land \lnot q) \rightarrow r \tag{2}\\ \\ & \equiv (\lnot p \lor q )\rightarrow r \tag{DeMorgan}\\ \\ & \equiv (p\rightarrow q)\rightarrow r\tag{1}\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you ver much but can you explain the reason behind (1)?

Comment: It holds by *definition*: how we define implication. Note that each side of the equivalence in $(1)$ is false if and only if $a$ is true and $b$ is false, and is true otherwise. While you're at it, compare the truth-tables for each side of the equivalence.

Comment: Can I infer that ¬a ∨ ¬b  ≡ a → ¬b ?

Comment: Yes indeed you can. You can also infer $a \lor \lnot b \equiv \lnot b \lor a \equiv b\rightarrow a \equiv \lnot a \rightarrow \lnot b$.

Comment: @amWhy: it is nice to have that ack from the OP! +1

Comment: Can you please explain why you used equivalent instead of equal to?

Answer (score 1):

Quantifiers are useless when what you're starting out with is a propositional formula, so your only hope is to express the result as something that consists of implications only.

And the only sensible way to make something into an implication is to match the pattern $A\to B \equiv \neg A\lor B$.

Simplifying to $(p\land\neg q)\lor r$ is good as far as it goes, but in order to become an implications, one of the operands to the $\lor$ will have to be the negation of something. Which one can you negate without reaching a dead end?